# python split string and pick substring

Tags: python

I am having a lot of trouble with the list returned by the split function in python.  I am probably being incredibly dense.

My python code is as follows

```
str = "XXX:YYY:ZZZ"
var+=1
ins = str.split(':')
print ins
```

When the script runs it returns the following result

```
['XXX','YYY','ZZZ']
```

What i am struggling to do is pull out the string contained the second string in the list.  I would have thought the following code at the end of the python code would work.

```
print ins[1]
```

but when i run it i get the following error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help would be much appreciated

full code

```
import time
ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)
print ser
time.sleep(3)
print "Sending serial data"
var = 0
while var<=10:
    str = ser.readline()
    print str
    var+=1
    ins = str.split(':')
    print ins
    print ins[0]
    if (str.split(':')=='end\n'):
        break
if(ser.isOpen()):
    print "Serial connection is still open."
    ser.close();
    print "Serial connectionnow terminated."
```

This returns

```
Serial<id=0x2a7fc50, open=True>(port='COM3', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
Sending serial data
Program Initiated

['Program Initiated\n']
Program Initiated

0:addsd:1

['0', 'addsd', '1\n']
0
1:addsd:2

['1', 'addsd', '2\n']
1
2:end:2

['2', 'end', '2\n']
2
```

Comment: Works for me.  Please post your exact code and exact error message (full traceback).

Comment: Works perfectly for me.  There's code you're not showing us though, `var` has no purpose, for instance. (It should also have a more descriptive name).  Without all the code we can't help you.

Comment: P.S. your comment says you want to pick the index of the result...care to elaborate on your title in the question? (Or change the title?)

Comment: @Sven Marnach The full code is a little more complicated as the string it is that i am trying to split is coming from an arduino mega via a comm port. The string appears to be working fine as i have done tests on it.  <p>full code will be added above

Comment: @Cpfohl have added the full code above.  It runs but only because i have not use print ins[1]

Comment: right after str.split(':') run the following: "print len(ins)" and let us know what the values are.  Also, this is still not the full code. `serial` is undefined.

Comment: The full error message would also be interesting.  Most probably you encounter strings that are split into only one segment.  Try `print len(ins)` to check the actual length of the returned lists.

Comment: @Cpfohl print len(ins) returns 1,3,3,3 which i believe is correct.  Serial is an import from pyserial is a python comm interface

Comment: @Sven Marnach the full error msg is<br>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test", line 12, in <module>
    print(ins[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: then ins[1] will not work for the first time through. You'll need to skip it.

Comment: @Cpfohl bingo.  i knew i was being incredibly dense.  Thnaks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not work in instances where the input you're analyzing has a length <= 1.

Try checking for that and handling it in your code.

Comment: as you were the first one to pick out my rookie mistake i have accepted your answer. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

One of the lines you are reading probably has a two '\n' characters in a row. When that string is read with readlines() and then spit it has no [1] index only a [0] index.

What output do you get for the program:

```
import serial // Or is serial a builtin for the version of python you are using?
print repr(serial.Serial("COM3", 9600))
```

Thanks,
    Marlen

Comment: @jklmuk I think there must be two '\n' characters in a row at some point.

Comment: output of print repr(ins) is:<br>['Program Initiated\n']
['0', 'addsd', '1\n']<br>
['1', 'addsd', '2\n']<br>
['2', 'end', '2\n']<br>

Comment: @jklmuk readline only reads up to a newline('\n') character if your string was "xxx:\n\n:xxx:yyy" I think your code wouldn't work.

Comment: @ marlen t. b. output is 'P'
'r'
'o'
'g'
'r'
'a'
'm'
' '
'I'
'n'
'i'
't'
'i'
'a'
't'
'e'
'd'
'\n'
'0'
':'
'a'
'd'
'd'
's'
'd'
':'
'1'
'\n'
'1'
':'
'a'
'd'
'd'
's'
'd'
':'
'2'
'\n'
'2'
':'
'e'
'n'
'd'
':'
'2'
'\n'

Comment: @marlen t. b. your updated answer is correct the first string being returned doesn't have and index 1 which was causing the problem thanks for you help

Comment: @jklmuk What python version are you using by the way? And what OS?

Comment: @jklmuk If your program is: `import time<br>print repr(serial.Serial("COM3", 9600))`, that is the out put? Give me a moment.

Comment: @jklmuk Can you post the answer as a block of code in your question? Comments have bad formatting for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Marlen T. B. what i showed you before isn't the complete program because it isn't finished.  For work i have to monitor the temperature of a gearbox in realtime, and to save time and money i offered up my arduino.  I have plenty of expeience programming arduino but have never made an interface between the computer and arduino.  Estially the plan is to send multiple temperature readings back to the python program and write the information to the hardrive as well as flash up warnings when i about to start an oil fire.  Should hopefully be able to get it finished tomorrow.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, cool. I was just trying to find the line of code that didn't work rather than telling you what I thought was wrong. Practice makes perfect I guess.